# How to solve a split display using a Radeon HD Graphic card?

Tags: ati, graphics, radeon

I am trying to install a new graphics card on my system and the screen comes up flashing, with the screen split in the middle.

The left edge of the screen meets the right edge of the screen in the middle.

Any suggestions?

Comment: When I attempt to signin, all I get is a blank flashing screen with no right mouse events.  I can't use a terminal to load the drivers.

Comment: Before your question can be answered, can you confirm what version of Ubuntu you are using also when you installed the new hardware what drivers did you install?  Did you use the Ubuntu binaries or did you install the latest AMD Catalyst?

Answer (score 1):

i have the same graphics card, amd-radeon 6670 manufactured by msi and amd a6 apu.

After installing 12.04 (amd64) I had to boot in recovery mode.

First choose Networking option to establish connection and remount hard drive in r/w.

Ctrl-D back to menu and choose the root console option.

Use `apt-get update` then `apt-get dist-upgrade`.

While possibly extraneous I update my `initramfs` and `update-grub` before rebooting.

Proprietary Catalyst driver worked pretty well, search for fglrx wiki and follow the distribution specific install guide.

Comment: -1  Why are you suggesting a distribution upgrade when its not clear what distro is being used.  Aslo there are good guide here at AU for installation of the proprietary catalyst, but  leveraging the Ubuntu binaries maybe sufficient

Comment: @StephenMyall `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` does not (by itself) upgrade to a newer OS release. `sudo apt-get upgrade` will never upgrade any packages that require any package to be removed or any package not already installed to be installed. `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` is the way to upgrade packages that do require those operations to be performed. It's originally called `dist-upgrade` because in other OSes like Debian where you do a release upgrade with `apt-get`/`aptitude`, you run that *after modifying `/etc/apt/sources.list`*. This answer is *not* saying to do a "distribution upgrade."